# How to add header fields and parameter to a GET request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, httpresponse

I want to send a GET request for JSON response back from server. Three parameters should be added to the header and with one parameter as a query string. Right now I am sending the request like this -

```
  NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.ngyripq.com/query?number=123456789"];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request addValue:@"my parameter 1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"parameter 1"];
  [request addValue:@"my parameter 2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"parameter 2"];

  DLog(@"%@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields])
  NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I am getting an error response in didReceiveResponse with status code: 404. Is there anything I am missing here..? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
   <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc28e7cddc0> { URL: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc28e7cddc0> { URL: https://www.ngyripq.com/query?number=123456789 } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = close;
   "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
   "Content-Length" = 205;
   "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
   Date = "Mon, 21 Sep 2015 17:05:27 GMT";
   Server = "Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)";
   Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
  "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1";
```

}  }

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Error 404 means Page Not Found if the developer is not throwing this error for other reasons.

First thing to do is to check if your url is fine. Then try to use POSTMAN (https://www.getpostman.com) to make the request to see if it works as it should.

Then create a request bin in this URL: http://requestb.in

and point your request to it, then you can see if your headers are fine.